# WordPress does not display elements to public without VPN

Tags: wordpress, azure, networking, custom-wordpress-pages

I have installed WordPress on the virtual machine in Azure. This virtual machine has external static IP and open 443 port. Additionally, this VM has internal IP for SSH. Internal IP accessibly only through VPN. Somehow, web sit requests some elements (CSS, pictures) via internal (private) IP and doesn't display without VPN. How to solve this situation and see all elements in a WordPress site without VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will need to configure the base path / base URL for your assets to the public IP that is listening to public traffic

One way to do this is via the administration panel itself

[image]